# SASS and LESS different behavior on variables pointing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

Given this snippet, imagine it can be LESS or SASS changing $ by @

```
$lol: 1px !default;
$lil: $lol;
$lol: 8px;

.gg{
  border-radius: $lil;
}
```

In SASS it compiles to

```
.gg {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

In Less it compiles to:

```
.gg {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

In my current situation, I prefer better how LESS implements it because the two first lines are in bootstrap lib and the third is supposed to overwrite the value of `lil`.

How could I overwrite the `$lil` variable in SASS by only changing the `$lol` variable?

Comment: In Sass you override variables by defining them *before* you import a lib (i.e. exactly in opposite of how you do it in Less). For more details on fundamental differences in variables semantics see for example this [blog post](https://getcrunch.co/2015/10/08/less-the-worlds-most-misunderstood-css-pre-processor/)).

Answer (score 1):

Because the sass variable has the !default parameter assigned, even though you are later changing it to 8px, it doesnt get assigned to that in sass.

from the SASS documentation

> You can assign to variables if they aren’t already assigned by adding
>   the  !default flag to the end of the value. This means that if the
>   variable has  already been assigned to, it won’t be re-assigned, but
>   if it doesn’t have a value yet it will be given one.